# i have error when creating google site page by imacro

Tags: imacros, google-sites

I built an imacros to create a page in google site of mine:

```
VERSION BUILD=8070701 RECORDER=CR SET !DATASOURCE my_source.csv 
SET !DATASOURCE_COLUMNS 2 
SET !LOOP 3 
SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{!LOOP}} 
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES 
SET !TIMEOUT_PAGE 2 

TAB T=1 

URL GOTO=https://sites.google.com/site/my_google_sites/ 
TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=ID:create-new-btn 
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:jot-ui-createForm ATTR=ID:jot-ui-pageName CONTENT={{!COL1}} 
TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=ID:createPageButton"
```

But in the line 10, when the code ran to the "Create Page" then it stop while the code was still running.
Can you help me!

Answer (score 0):

Use EVENT TYPE=CLICK for your Button "Create Page". Or you can use "Record Options" and then "Experimental event recording mode" for your record function.

Example:

```
SET !DATASOURCE my_source.csv
SET !DATASOURCE_COLUMNS 2
SET !LOOP 3
SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{!LOOP}}
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
SET !TIMEOUT_PAGE 2
TAB T=1
URL GOTO=https://sites.google.com/site/my_google_sites/
EVENT TYPE=CLICK SELECTOR="#create-new-btn" BUTTON=0
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:jot-ui-createForm ATTR=ID:jot-ui-pageName CONTENT={{!COL1}}
EVENT TYPE=CLICK SELECTOR="#createPageButton" BUTTON=0
```